# Custom Tab and Custom Object are same

Tags: custom-object

Can any one let me know is Custom Tab and Custom Object the same.If yes then in my EE i do get ab ERROR as : Custom Tab Limit Exceeded 
Your organization's edition of salesforce.com has a limit of 25 custom tabs. To learn about options for increasing your organization's custom tab limits, please contact your account executive.Basically for custom object we can create upto 800.

Answer (score 2):

Custom Tab and Custom Object are not same.

Custom object are custom database tables that allow you to store information unique to your organization.

While tab is one of the ways for provisioning users to access these objects for creation of data for salesforce object

Every object may not have tab while if you have a tab (Custom Object)  then it implies there is an underlying object.(Note tab can be a visualforce tab as well).

The reason you are getting this issue is your org has a limit that you can create only 10 tabs ,note that it does not imply you cannot create more than 10 objects .

Would recommend you to go through force.com fundamentals for more info on tabs,apps and objects

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/

Answer (score 0):

- Custom tabs are totally different from custom object and have different limits as well.
- When you create a custom object you have an option by which you can create a custom tab for that object as well.
- This custom tab will provide you a UI interface for your object records.
- In EE you are provided 25 custom tabs.
- You can ask salesforce to increase your custom tabs limit (paid)
- In performance edition this limit is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

In Enterprise addition you can not create more that 25 tabs. Custom objects and Custom tab are different components.

You can not create more than 200 custom objects in EE edition. ( *800 ?* )

Custom tabs provide user interaction with Custom objects while Custom object provides data storing structure.

Refer to: [Custom Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_custom_objects.htm) and [Custom Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_tabdef.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: @Mohith Shrivastava,@sales_lion,@regal :Thanks for your reply.If i want to know what are the Custom Tabs ,Where can i find it?Can any one help me out with the navigation??

Comment: @nikkey I have given two links in answer. Did you get chance to open them?